# KeyError: '\n' while Unpickling in Python 2.7.10

Tags: python, pickle

I have a list of tuples of the form `activity_list=[('text 1', 'text 2', "('No recent activity',)")........]`, which I have pickled into a file as

```
with open('file.dat', 'wb') as writefile:
    pickle.dump(activity_list, writefile, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

However, when I try to Unpickle this file using

```
if os.path.isfile('file.dat') and os.stat('file.dat').st_size!=0:
        with open('file.dat', 'rb') as myfile:
                activitydata=pickle.load(myfile)
                print activitydata
```

I get the following error:

```
`Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\CMS downloader\cms-dl\gui.py", line 117, in show_last
    activitydata=pickle.load(myfile)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
KeyError: '\n'
```

What **EXACTLY** is the reason for this error,and how can I solve it ?

Code:
`

```
import pickle
import os
activity_list=[('Activity since Thursday, 6 October 2016, 3:18 AM', 'CS/ECE/EEE/INSTR F215 DIGITAL DESIGN LS1', "('No recent activity',)"), ('Activity since Thursday, 6 October 2016, 3:18 AM', 'ECE/EEE/INSTR F211 ELECTRICAL MACHINES LS1', "('No recent activity',)")]
with open('activity.dat', 'wb') as writefile:
    pickle.dump(activity_list, writefile, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
if os.path.isfile('activity.dat') and os.stat('activity.dat').st_size!=0:
    with open('activity.dat', 'rb') as myfile:
        print repr(myfile.read())
        activitydata=pickle.load(myfile)
        print activitydata
```

'
Output:
'

```
"\x80\x02]q\x00(U0Activity since Thursday, 6 October 2016, 3:18 AMq\x01U(CS/ECE/EEE/INSTR F215 DIGITAL DESIGN LS1q\x02U\x17('No recent activity',)q\x03\x87q\x04U0Activity since Thursday, 6 October 2016, 3:18 AMq\x05U*ECE/EEE/INSTR F211 ELECTRICAL MACHINES LS1q\x06U\x17('No recent activity',)q\x07\x87q\x08e."

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/CMS downloader/cms-dl/lol.py", line 9, in <module>
    activitydata=pickle.load(myfile)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 880, in load_eof
    raise EOFError
EOFError
```

`

Comment: A newline character was found where the pickle module expected a type dispatch byte. Is this **exactly** the code that produces the file? Nothing else manipulates that file in any way?

Comment: Yes.Nothing else manipulates the file in any way whatsoever.

Comment: What does `with open('file.dat', 'rb') as myfile:`, `print repr(myfile.read())` produce?

Comment: And given *just* the code here and the sample `activitydata` list reduced to just the one tuple, I can't reproduce this.

Comment: Last but not least, a CP1252 decoding of the data *I* have, gives me subtly different data, but that may be due to you having included more tuples. I'm also using 2.7.12, but scanning the [detailed release history](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v2.7.12/Misc/NEWS) doesn't show any relevant changes to `pickle`.

Comment: This is what repr(myfile.read()) gives (text too large to be typed here) :
[link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9s7RuI739tuZEVDQ0dzNnZGM1E)
P.S. text1 and text2 correspond to 'Activity since .....2:46 AM' and 'CS/ECE.......LS1' respectively,i.e. to say they always have the same format.

Comment: Perhaps you could try and reproduce this with a smaller dataset so that the `repr()` does fit in the question?

Comment: And the data you gave gives me `KeyError: '\x07'`, not `\n`, interestingly enough.

Comment: Have tried repr() with just two tuples now, updated in question.

Comment: Groan Mode: On. `print repr(myfile.read())` leaves the file pointer at end-of-file. `myfile.seek(0)` will fix it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - the Lastactivity.dat file from the link loaded for me without an error. Python 2.7.6 on linux mint.

Comment: @nik_97 sorry; out of time for today. I'll try to check this again tomorrow.

Comment: @nik_97: I can't reproduce your error. I get *different output* for the same `activity_list` you produced, but I have no trouble loading the `repr()` output you added to the question either. Your `EOFError` is due to you having read the file already, as tdelaney already pointed out, you need a `myfile.seek(0)` before doing `pickle.load(my_file)`. Alternatively, use `data = myfile.read()`, then `print(repr(data))` and `activitydata = pickle.loads(data)` (note the `s` in `loads`).

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I'm having exactly the same issue trying to load `mappings.pkl` here: https://github.com/glample/tagger/tree/master/models/english .